# How to solve an expression with big exponents?(Example in Body)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This problem was on a math competition on a no calculator section. How can it be solved without a calculator? The problem is to find the remainder of : $\frac{10^9+23^9}{11}$.

Comment: What level competition was this?  Are you sure you weren't asked simply to show that this was an integer?

Comment: Ah, the _remainder_... that makes a huge difference... :)

Comment: Normally, the term remainder refers to the smallest non-negative integer that is congruent to the original number, based on the pertinent modulus.  It is often helpful, when (for example) working with a modulus like $11$, to consider the remainders (AKA congruence classes) of $S = \{-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}.$ If $a \equiv b\pmod{c}$, then $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod{c}.$  Ask yourself, what element $(a)$  from the set $S$ is such that $10 \equiv a\pmod{11}$?  Similarly, what element element $b$ from the set $S$ is such that $23 \equiv b\pmod{11}$?

Comment: $10^9=(11-1)^9$, $23^9=(22+1)^9$.

Comment: $\!\bmod 11\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{10\equiv -1},\, \color{#0a0}{23\equiv 1}\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{10}^9 +\color{#0a0}{23}^9\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}^9+\color{#0a0}1^9\equiv -1+1\equiv 0\,$ by basic [congruence arithmetic rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 3):

Modular arithmetic is certainly one option, but for those who may not be too well versed in it, another option is simply using the identity $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$:
$$10^9+23^9=(10^3)^3+(23^3)^3=(10^6-10^3\times23^3+23^6)(10^3+23^3)$$
$$=(10^6-10^3\times23^3+23^6)(10^2-10\times23+23^2)(10+23)$$
$$=33(10^6-10^3\times23^3+23^6)(10^2-10\times23+23^2)$$
Since the number has a factor of 33 in it, dividing it by 11 will give a 0 remainder.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Essentially instead of evaluating the exponents directly, you can discard most of the information at each step.
$$10^2\equiv 100\equiv 1+9\cdot11\equiv 1\pmod{11}$$
Thus, you can see that
$$10^9\equiv 10(10^8)\equiv 10(10^2)^4\equiv 10(1^4)\equiv 10 \pmod{11}$$
And since
$$23=1+2\cdot 11$$
$$23^9\equiv 1^9\equiv 1\pmod{11}$$
And so the remainder of the division is $10^9+23^9\pmod{11}=0$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).